# Instantiate CompilationUnitEditor for usage in a custom Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I currently work on a custom Eclipse plugin. The plugin expects the user to type in some Java code, so I want Code Assistance for that. The plugin looks like this so far
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/findreplace-regular-expressions-and-match-evaluators#group-screenshots .

Now my idea was to instantiate a CompilationUnitEditor, e.g. like this

```
CompilationUnitEditor javaEditor = new CompilationUnitEditor();
Composite placeWhereINeedToHaveIt = new Composite(...
...
javaEditor.createPartControl(placeWhereINeedToHaveIt);
```

The problem with above code is that I didn't set the EditorInput (i.e. the CompilationUnit ) for the javaEditor, but there is no public method on CompilationUnitEditor allowing me to do this.

What can I do? Any help is appreciated!

I also would like to have the source code for CompilationUnitEditor in my Eclipse IDE. Right know if I hit Alt+Shift+F1 on an active JavaEditor (activating the Eclipse Spy) and then click on CompilationUnitEditor, the source code isn't shown.

Comment: Since this is an editor it implements `IEditorPart` so you can call the `init` method. But you will have to provide an `IEditorSite` and everything that an editor part expects to have available.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the init method is what I was looking for. But which subclass of IEditorInput do I need to provide? Where can I find the Eclipse code that's executed when you doubleclick on a Java source file?

Comment: For a file in the workspace it is `FileEditInput`. There is a huge amount of code executed when you open an editor. You should also note that `CompilationUnitEditor` is an **internal** class, you are violating the terms of the [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) by using it like this.